# Query on aggregate table takes longer time than the query on the raw data

Tags: google-bigquery

i wanted to shorten the execution time of the query, so i created a new aggregated table based on the raw data, but for some reason the original query is mach faster than the new query based on the aggregated table. 
Both of the queries return the same results.

Why is this happening?

thank!

Comment: Could you please add a few job id's that may help the BQ team to verify it. Also how long are we talking about?

Comment: The query based on the aggregate table:playscape-proj:job_Ux-sepfxMp8PI1GXyuoiVdgxHMI.  The original query : playscape-proj:job_X-EYicJ_zMR_Lub93Oxtxz6ld8Q.  The original query takes about 70 sec and the new one takes 100 sec. Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you for including the jobids in your comment. That makes it much easier to debug. Can you also please tell me how you did the aggregation of the table for the second query? Either the SQL you used or the jobid would be helpful.

Here is what I see so far:
* You got roughly a 10x reduction in bytes processed and total rows by aggregating.
* Aggregating also resulted in a 10x reduction in the number of partitions for your table (21 -> 2).

Since BigQuery dispatches one worker per partition typically, we wouldn't expect much difference in execution time in this case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer! I'll try other ways to reduce the execution time. The JobID: job_QJScEq3hEiPkYkUafD-jgzwC3tA.